# Installing a php extension with Macports

Tags: macports, php-extension

I would like to install the `php-intl` extension for PHP on my Mac. I know the current PHP installation was installed with the OS (Mac OS X 10.6).

So I am wondering if I install the `php5-intl` package using Macports, will it install a second version of PHP (which I don't want), or will it upgrade my existing installation?

If I can't upgrade my current PHP installation that way, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the MacPorts php5-intl port will install PHP's intl extension for use with MacPorts php5, which it will also install; you'll also get MacPorts' copy of the apache2 server. [MacPorts is designed to be self-contained](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#ownlibs); it's not designed to modify or integrate with any software components Apple provided with your OS. This is a good thing; Apple occasionally makes unexpectedly changes to their OS components which could break things installed by MacPorts.

If you want to give MacPorts apache2 and php5 a try, check out the [MacPorts MAMP guide](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP) in the wiki.